# Product Specification in table grid view in magento..!

Tags: php, magento

I m inserting the data in description in magento...!!
but I'm getting a paragraph...!!
but inorder to get tabular format I had to write the HTML code manually.
So is there any solutions to get the  tabular format autmatically.

For example follow below pic:

[image]

Comment: Where is the image??How you want it?

Comment: I dont have 10 reputations so it's not allowing me to add images...!!!
i want specification in tabular format I had created Attributes set for that...!!!

Comment: So do you have a problem with '<p>' Tag only?

Comment: I guess now you can add image

Comment: I want to insert the data via admin panel..!!
bt fetch it in a Tabular format as show in above Pic...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Create maximum attributes for specification add those.

like spec_1.spec_2,......

then display those attributes values in specification section in table format.

For example:

```
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table-4">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php if (0 == strcmp($attributeSetName, 'Clothing')): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Clothing Shape</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getClothing_shape() ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Outer Fabric</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getOuter_fabric() ?></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Clothing Lining</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getClothing_lining() ?></td>
            </tr>   
        <?php elseif (0 == strcmp($attributeSetName, 'Sleeping Bags')): ?>      
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Outer Fabric</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getOuter_fabric() ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Inner Fabric</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getInner_fabric() ?></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <th class="label">Filling</th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getFilling() ?></td>
            </tr>   
        <?php endif; ?>     
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-4')</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want it? If you want it in product detail page then edit in catalog\product\view.phtml

Comment: if you are using tab for specification then related file may be (catalog\product\view\tabs.phtml) or catalog\product\view/specification.phtml  or catalog\product\specification.phtml else edit in catalog\product\view.phtml. The file depend upon the custom theme you are using.